# Origin of "no." abbreviation in meaning of "number"?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations

I Russian speaker and we have **№** sign for American **#**.

But I surprised that there are uses of [**No.** abbreviation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/no.) as shortened form of *number*.

What the origin of "no." abbreviation in meaning of "number"?

Because it must be **nu** or **num**... Is that come from Latin?

Answer (score 4):

The "no." abbreviation of number is Latin in origin, a short form of **numero**. See http://latin-phrases.co.uk/abbreviations/ for other examples of Latin abbreviations.